# Export from gridview to csv format

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a gridview with 5 columns in asp.net and want to export only two columns with semicolon (`DBS30606XRIR;1,748.09`) in csv format. I can able to export it.but my question is when the price column in gridview contains comma it is going to another cell in the file after export. I want it in one cell only. Below is my code.

```
If GVuplaodPriceList.Rows.Count <> 0 Then

        Dim sw As TextWriter = New StreamWriter("U:\ListPrice.csv")
        For i As Integer = 0 To GVuplaodPriceList.Rows.Count - 1

            sw.Write(GVuplaodPriceList.Rows(i).Cells(4).Text.ToString() + ";")
            sw.Write(GVuplaodPriceList.Rows(i).Cells(5).Text.ToString())
            sw.WriteLine()
        Next

        sw.WriteLine("")

        sw.Close()
        MsgBox("Data Exported Successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Data Exported")
```

Comment: Wrap your exported values in double quotes and it should resolve the issue.

Comment: Sorry Mr.Mort i did not get it since i am a beginner in programming.could you please advice me in little details.thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - wrap in quotes:

```
sw.Write(String.Concat("""",GVuplaodPriceList.Rows(i).Cells(5).Text.ToString(),"""",";"))
```

Option 2 - remove offending comma

```
sw.Write(String.Concat(GVuplaodPriceList.Rows(i).Cells(5).Text.ToString.Replace("""", ""),";"))
```

Comment: Hello Mort.Thanks but still the same.exported csv file is not  in this format (DBS30606XRIR;1,748.09) instead one cell contains DBS30606XRIR;1 and another cell contains  the remaining value 748.09. i used both the above options.same out put.

Comment: Can you see the inverted commas when you open the csv in a text editor?

Comment: No inverted commas. out put it( DBS30606XRIR;1   748.09 ) one cell contains DBS30606XRIR;1 and another cell contains the remaining value 748.09

Comment: Add a string variable and assign it to the result of the replace. See that you are getting the correct result before you write to file.